# clojure find last element without using last function

Tags: clojure

I'm learning clojure and have been using [4clojure.com](http://www.4clojure.com/problems) to get better. I just completed [#19](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/19) but it seems like maybe I haven't done it quite as the author's have anticipated - like I've perhaps missed the point somehow.

[image: 4 clojure problem 19]

Given the constraint that **you cannot use the last function** does this seem like a reasonable solution?

```
#(.get %(- (count %) 1))
```

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I did nearly the exact same thing, except I used `nth`. `4clojure` is great!

Comment: IMHO this approach is just to make it work around the restriction, but not really acceptable as a learning task. Learning functional programming is about learning a new way of problem solving and thinking in general. `object something = list.get(n - 1);` is not quite that, is it? I suggest to look at answer by @Alex Taggart.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's a valid solution. I would go with `#(nth % (dec (count %)))` as being more idiomatic, but they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: Please say why it's more "idiomatic".  It will help Clojure students:-)

Comment: @devdanke in this case the fact that there is a `dec` function in Clojure that decrements is a strong hint.

Comment: Although I upvoted the answer below that returns the first element of reversed coll, your answer is more efficient (upvoted, too :))
Inspired by [this](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/last#example-5967ad3ce4b0d19c2ce9d6f9) measurement (and hint), I applied it to both asnwers:

- `(time (nth large-v (dec(count large-v))))` ; "Elapsed time: 0.138563 msecs"
- `(time (first (reverse large-v))))` ; "Elapsed time: 23.901557 msecs"

Yeah, those are milliseconds. For much smaller colls we will not probably feel the difference, but I hope this will still be usefull to know.

Answer (score 43):

If you're going to use:

```
#(first (reverse %))
```

You might as well compose the function with "comp":

```
(comp first reverse)
```

This is probably a little more idiomatic and easier to read.  The same caveat about "reverse" not being lazy applies here.

Comment: Bet they wanted users to write this answer, not strange ones with [length-1]

Comment: This is what I came up with as well. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 23):

What about

```
reduce (fn [a b] b)
```

In the blank

Answer (score 20):

Here's a purely recursive approach that doesn't rely on counting:

```
(defn end [[n & more]]
  (if more
    (recur more)
    n))
```

Comment: Of course not, this defines a function called `end` that returns the last element in a sequence. What you are looking for is:
`(fn [[n & more]] (if more (recur more) n))`

Answer (score 8):

Yeah that's a reasonable solution. A few things though:

1. It's more idiomatic to use the function `dec` instead of subtracting by one.

   `#(.get % (dec (count %)))`
2. Follow other people on 4clojure. That way you can see their solutions to the problem after you solve it. I'm working through 4clojure myself and find it very useful to learn about the language, especially certain idioms.
3. The first solution I thought of would just be to reverse the list and take the first element.

   `#(first (reverse %))`

Comment: Ha, I like the #3 solution, but it seems almost like cheating ;)

Comment: If the seq were really big then `reverse` wouldn't be great (as it duplicates the sequence in memory), but given this is a trivial little problem that's somewhat irrelevant. Also, `nth` is more idiomatic than `.get`.

Comment: @mange yes, reverse isn't lazy. but it would be cool to create lazy-reverse and use this idiom.

Comment: In fairness, the `count/nth` solution is just as non-lazy as a `reverse` solution: both will fail on very large input sequences. And sadly, @ivant, a lazy reverse of a lazy sequence is not possible.

Comment: I'm not talking laziness. `reverse` will duplicate the structure (it may be more intelligent for a vector with random access, but it can't be for a list/arbitrary seq). The `count`/`nth` solution shouldn't fail for anything that can fit in memory.

Comment: @mange: There is a function `rseq` which just accesses the collection in reverse order in place. Of course, the collection then must be with random access and finite, like vector.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think my solution is better than anyone else but I think it is another way of solving the same problem:

```
(fn 
  [x] 
  (nth x (- (count x) 1)))
```

This is using the `fn`.

Comment: Why actually someone -1 this? This is a correct solution.

Comment: I guess someone expected him to use dec instead of (- (count x) 1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get even simpler with something like `(comp peek vec)`. I think the problem is that `last` is working with sequences and works in linear time as the documentation says:

> clojure.core/last ([coll])   Return the last item in coll, in linear
>   time

`peek` on the other hand is faster than `last` according to the docs:

> clojure.core/peek ([coll])   For a list or queue, same as first, for a
>   vector, same as, but much   more efficient than, last. If the
>   collection is empty, returns nil.

Comment: Note that converting a list to a vector takes linear time, and allocates memory. By doing science (read: using (time) three times on each and eye-balling the numbers), I have concluded that vec-and-peek is slower than last.  If you're going to do (last) on the same list _a lot_, it might pay to convert it to a vector up front, because one `(vec)` at θ(n) plus n `(peek)`s at θ(1) is θ(n) whereas n `(last)`s at θ(n) is θ(n²).  It might also pay off in different ways to write readable code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(fn getLast [l] (if (= (count l) 1) (first l) (getLast (rest l))) )
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please? Code only answers might answer the question but they don't teach people why you did this.

Comment: This works similarly to `last` except that it will be O(n²) for sequences that aren't counted (such as lazy seqs) due to the fact that `count` itself will be O(n) and get called on each iteration.